# Difference between harmonic (vocalized) and non (consonant) sounds

Tags: python, audio, signals, signal-processing

I'm new at Digital signal processing. I have to do this exercise using Python:

> Analysis of vocal traces with the STFT trying to identify the parts of
> the signal related to harmonic (vocalized) and non (consonant) sounds.
> In the case of non-harmonic sounds, you can try to estimate the AR
> model and then filter out some random noise with the same model.
> Listening should be able to recognize the original sound.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do! I don't really know where to start! I was wondering what the difference was between harmonic (vocalized) and non (consonant) sounds. what is an example of these two types? What topics do I need to know to do this exercise? Can anyone explain this exercise to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these pages

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Music/vowel.html
[http://my.ilstu.edu/~jsawyer/consonantsvowels/consonantsvowels_print.html](http://my.ilstu.edu/%7Ejsawyer/consonantsvowels/consonantsvowels_print.html)

In a very plain answer I would say that vowels have peaks in the spectrum, while the consonants are filtered continuous spectrum noise. This will be clearer for the unvoiced fricative consonants, like /f/, /s/. Not so much for the plosives (due to the relatively short duration).